# Python/Pandas: How to remove salutations like MR., MS., MISS from a column of a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe column that looks like this

| Name |
| --- |
| Miss Hello |
| Mr. Idiot |
| Ms. Good |

I need the output of a transformation to be:

| Name |
| --- |
| Hello |
| Idiot |
| Good |

Can someone please help how to do this in python?

Comment: Anything tried yourself?

Answer (score 2):

If each value has prefix and is possible remove values bfore first space use [`Series.str.split`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.split.html) with `n=1` and then select second list by indexing `str[1]`:

```
print (df)
               Name
0  Miss Hello World
1         Mr. Idiot
2  Ms. Good Morning

df['Name'] = df['Name'].str.split(n=1).str[1]

print (df)
           Name
0   Hello World
1         Idiot
2  Good Morning
```

Or if need replace only prefixes use [`Series.replace`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.replace.html) with list, but is necessary escape `.` because special regex character:

```
df['Name'] = df['Name'].replace(['Miss ','Mr\. ','Ms\. '],'', regex=True)

print (df)
           Name
0   Hello World
1         Idiot
2  Good Morning
```

Comment: Few rows may have salutations and few rows may not have

Comment: @Sai - Then use second solution with `replace`